# Parser to extract foreground background color pairs

Tags: javascript, html, css, colors

Assuming that the webpage is static and only source of colors are present either in the CSS files or in HTML file itself, how to extract foreground background color pairs from a webpage. 
For example in Google home page, some of the possible color pairs would be (assuming GOOGLE is a text):

(Foreground,Background) : (blue,white), (Red,white), (Yellow,white), (Green, white), (blue,white), (Green, white).

The approach which I am thinking about is that we can check the DOM tree structure of a webpage then start from root node HTML. (Foreground,Background) assigned to a parent tag in html or in CSS would be the default color of all of its children. But if a child belongs to a specific class in CSS then the color property defined in that class would override parent's colors. Please give your suggestions about this or alternative ways/tools to get the result.

Comment: You could use [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getComputedStyle), but it won't return 'red', most likely it will return rgba in newer browsers, rgb in older browsers, and maybe hex in really old browsers, so good luck with that.

Answer (score 1):

here is my function for iterating childrens

```
function iterateChildren(elem){
      var child = elem.children();
    $.each(child,function(i,v){
        iterateChildren($(this));
          var pair = {fgHex:rgb2hex($(this).css('color')),bgHex:rgb2hex($(this).css('background-color'))};
      colorPair.push(pair);
      var tmp = {nodeName:$(this).get(0).nodeName,id:$(this).attr('id'),cssClass:$(this).attr('class'),colrhex:rgb2hex($(this).css('color')),colr:$(this).css('color'),bg:$(this).css('background-color'),bgHex:rgb2hex($(this).css('background-color'))};
          result.push(tmp);
    });    
}
```

And you can call it like the below:

```
var elems = $('body');
iterateChildren(elems);
```

I have created a fiddle for you [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7qr7q/)

Comment: Did you use the same approach that I mentioned?

Comment: In this fiddle, 'Child1' should show '#ffffff' as foreground and '#0000ff' as background. But it doesnt not show the background.

Comment: It is showing only pairs which are defined in the CSS. But I need to find pairs as we see on webpage. Like in the example you created, it should return 3 pairs: (white,blue),(yellow,blue), (black,yellow).